# Can you please center the site like all other StackExchange sites?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Physics is left-justified on Chrome.

Is it intentional?

Comment: I think the CSS is messed up because the "post-signature" class above is being rendered on top of the "hot meta posts" sidebar.

Comment: Probably a multiple duplicate. There have been [ongoing problems with chrome](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=chrome) and it has generally been on the chrome side.

Comment: (a) Isn't left justification good? (as in, why would you want right or centered justification?) (b) I'm getting a misalignment on Opera 12.16

Comment: The notion that it's the CSS [may have some merit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253550/the-question-is-misaligned-too-far-to-the-right).

Comment: How can it "be on the Chrome side". It is never on the Chrome side. Name one time it has ever been on the Chrome side.

Comment: @John  the most annoying one is [this one](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/the-site-toolbar-looks-broken-in-chrome-how-can-i-fix-it) (and see the Linked sidebar for the slew of duplicates).

Comment: @Emilio and yet... it is only this stack exchange site with the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A fix for this is rolling out now.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253555/130213)